# Removing null and empty objects from the JSON Response(Spring REST) with empty object inside empty object

Tags: java, json

I want to remove the Null and Empty values from my JSON Response.

Below is Json String:

```
{"implDisplayablePricePlan": [
          {
            "productSpecPricing": {
              "childPricingSchema": {}
            },
            "assignedPricePlanID": "abc",
            "name": "GOLD",
            "action": "Something",
            "status": "Something",
            "selected": true,
            "crossProductDiscount": false,

            "displayInformation": {
              "visible": true,
              "enabled": false
            }
          }]
```

}

in this case : productSpecPricing with childPricingSchema

What will be best approach to remove empty objects which will be generic for any JSON String.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) you can easy set your preferences to serialize your objects

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
ObjectWriter writer = objectMapper.writer();
System.out.println(writer.writeValueAsString(YOUR_OBJECT));
```

I got this:

```
{
  "implDisplayablePricePlan" : [ {
    "productSpecPricing" : { },
    "assignedPricePlanID" : "abc",
    "name" : "GOLD",
    "action" : "Something",
    "status" : "Something",
    "selected" : true,
    "crossProductDiscount" : false,
    "displayInformation" : {
      "visible" : true,
      "enalble" : false
    }
  } ]
}
```

as `productSpecPricing` isn't null (or empty array/collection) it's shown, to solve it you have to add a filter:

annotate the class that contains the `productSpecPricing` property with `@JsonFilter("myFilter")`

```
FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("myFilter", filter);
ObjectWriter writer = objectMapper.writer(filters);
```

Filter:

```
PropertyFilter filter = new SimpleBeanPropertyFilter() {

    @Override
    public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider, PropertyWriter writer)
                    throws Exception {
        if (include(writer)) {
            System.out.println(writer.getName());
            if (!writer.getName().equals("productSpecPricing")) {
                writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
                return;
            } else {
                ProductSpecPricing productSpecPricing = ((YOU_OBJECT) pojo).getProductSpecPricing();
                if (productSpecPricing != null && productSpecPricing.getChildPricingSchema() != null && !productSpecPricing.getChildPricingSchema().isEmpty()) {
                    writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
                }
            }
        } else if (!jgen.canOmitFields()) {
            writer.serializeAsOmittedField(pojo, jgen, provider);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

after apply the filter the result is:

```
{
  "implDisplayablePricePlan" : [ {
    "assignedPricePlanID" : "abc",
    "name" : "GOLD",
    "action" : "Something",
    "status" : "Something",
    "selected" : true,
    "crossProductDiscount" : false,
    "displayInformation" : {
      "visible" : true,
      "enalble" : false
    }
  } ]
}
```

Comment: I have REST classes which are configured using @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) So i am looking for capturing the JSON in the Reponse Body and remove all the null or empty values. I am new to REST and Springs so probably some thing might be lost in translation. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: ... so you are not the one generating that json?, you are using Spring?, you should give revelant info in your question

Comment: I am using @Path("/somepath")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  at the top of my interfaceclass which is generating Json reponse...

Comment: This even works with Spring as it typically uses Jackson. You have to configure the message converter (see `MappingJackson2MessageConverter.setObjectMapper()`)

Comment: yes, but I had proposed extend the `ObjectMapper` to add the settings and set it as message converter

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are getting/creating the JSON file.

If you are creating it, then, during creation, if a value is non-existant, null, void or any other you do not desire, do not insert it.

However, if you are receiving this JSON from others, then during parse, get the key/pair value, again, if you do not want it, do not add to your object.

Without details from your program, we cant help further

#### Edit 1:

This code in PHP is (adapted from the one I use):

```
$input = file_get_contents($name, "r");
if($input != FALSE) {
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($input);$i++){
        if($input[$i]=='{'){
            $begin= $i;
        } else if($input[$i]=='}'){
            $buffer .= substr($input,$begin,$i-$begin+1) .",";
            if (strpos($buffer,'":null') !== false) {
                // Drop the current line
            } else {
                // Line is correct, keep on writting
            }
            if($counter>=100 ){
                $counter= 0;
                save($buffer);
                $buffer = "";
            }
        } else if($input[$i]==']'){
            save($buffer);
            $buffer = "";
            $i = strlen($input);
        }
    }


}
```

In it, we will first successfully get the JSON file. Then, open the file, read each "section" (or object) of a JSON structure, then do as we must (in my case, I would fix the input, but I guess you can just drop it.)

Comment: I am having REST(with Spring) services which produces JSON. so when it is displayed it is showing empty objects. I want to remove empty objects before it is displayed as JSON in REST service. Using Object Mapper in Spring xml is also not working. I hope there is generic way to go about this for any REST call.

Comment: Then how about reading the input as a file, iterating the content, and check after `":null` and  `":""`?

Comment: This isjust tip of iceberg. file is huge.

Comment: Yes, but you are receiving the file anyway, and as far as I know, most systems will read JSONs as a single input (and load it completely on RAM)

Comment: is it possible. could you please help me with it cause i tried readTree functionality and it didn't work. Some sample example will do the trick

Comment: I would approach the issue with [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html), and either [read lines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) or [read all lines if you got RAM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

Comment: how would you remove : for sample {
            "productSpecPricing": {
              "childPricingSchema": {}
            }  by your approach.

Comment: I am using PHP in my system, and therefore, I will receive a file, replace strings, then continue operations....I will edit the question to post example code.